# pandas difference in append/concat between version 0.23 and 1.1.5

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wrote a piece of code that appends df one after another
for some reason it works fine at 0.23 but when i accidentally installed pandas 1.1.5 it stopped working and i got this error:

```
number of manager items must equal union of block items
# manager items: 453, # tot_items: 454
```

and the amount of columns are the same.
someone has any idea why?

Comment: then use `concat()` method....also it is more flexible and powerful than `append()` method

Comment: @AnuragDabas tried still doesn't work I also tries ignore_index=True still nothing

Comment: can you please post a part of your both df's with expected output that you are trying to concat

Comment: @AnuragDabas sadly it has 10,000 rows so i dont know if its possible and i dont know where the problem is so i cant reduce it

Comment: I just need a part of it....just post the output of `df1.head()` and `df2.head()` and your expected output from these 2 df's